# how can i res.send() to a specific id of an html tag? - Node js

Tags: html, node.js, express

I have search.html with this form:

```
 <form class="myform" action="/classi"  autocomplete="on">
<input type="text" name="search" >
<button type="submit"  ></button>
```

when i press the button:

index.js:

```
  router.get('/classi',function(req,res,next){

  res.send("ciaoo")

});
```

I want to send the text "ciaoo" to a specific id of my html tag in another page html "classi.html".

classi.html

```
 <head>
<body>
<h1 id="ciao"></h1>
</body>
</head>
```

How can I do? Thanks

Comment: Show us what have you tried. You have to get this value by making another HTTP request, preferably by javascript and then insert the value to the desired object of DOM using innerHTML or innerText property

Comment: yes, but I do not know how to do it, I'm a beginner

Comment: I modified my question to explain better

Answer (score 0):

For that, you have to add a script in your HTML file and then you can communicate through ajax call and modify your HTML through the script.

Make a JS file and include the file in HTML and follow these steps -

> 1. Make an AJAX call(GET ..../classi) to your server using XMLHttpRequest.
> 2. Get response in callback (or in then if using promise).
> 3. Modify the HTML with the response.

Comment: I modified my question to explain better